# Display all categories linked to an article

Tags: twig

I make a loop to browse the categories linked to my articles but if an article with several categories it displays the name of my first category as many times as there are categories.

How do I display all the names?
Here Gary Moore in 2 categories: blues and metal but blues is displayed 2 times.

```
{% for category in articleDer.category %}
   {% if category.articles | length >=1 %}
      <a class="textPostcard" href="{{ path('portcategory_categorie', {'slug': category.slug }) }}"><i class="fas fa-list-alt mr-2"></i> &nbsp;{{ articleDer.category[0].name }}</a>
   {% else %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: `{{ articleDer.category[0].name }}` should more probably be `{{ category.name }}` or something the like. But without any information on your entities, this is just plain guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you are looping `articleDer.category` array and printing `<a class="textPostcard" ...></a>`.

But inside the loop you are accessing only the first index of the  `articleDer.category` and fetching the name.

In your code,

```
{{ articleDer.category[0].name }}
```

Should be changed to

```
{{ category.name }}
```